# Why does AEM dispatcher refuse to connect?

Tags: apache, aem, dispatcher

I tried to follow the instruction from

```
https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kt/platform-repository/using/dispatcher-macos-technical-video-setup.html
```

to set up an AEM dispatcher on my MacBook.

The version of my operating system is Catalina 10.15.1, so there should not be an issue of macOS Mojave. Since AEM does not support builtin Apache anymore, I installed brew's Apache on homebrew. Then, I start my AEM server on my localhost:4053, and started my Apache dispatcher.

Then, I go to the following link:

```
http://aem-publish.local/content/we-retail/us/en.html
```

It gave the error of

```
aem-publish.local refused to connect.
```

[image]

What can be possibly causing this error?

Comment: There are two obvious things to check first. Make sure aem-publish.local resolves to 127.0.0.1 and make sure apache is actually running.

Comment: Yes, I have checked those two things, and they have no issues.

Comment: The fact that you get a can't be reached response means that apache is either not running or you are not hitting it properly. You should double check that apache is running and is bound to port 80.

Comment: Port 80? When I do "sudo apachectl status" without starting Apache, it says "Looking up localhost:8080
Making HTTP connection to localhost:8080" it connects to port 8080 by default.

Comment: Let me change the port to 80 to see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was just that The tutorial uses port 80, but Apache uses port 8080 by default.

I just have to change the port number to 8080 on aem-publish.local.conf file.

Or, I can change the port number to 80 in httpd.conf file.

Comment: When you specify a url that starts with http it defaults to port 80. Since you established that apache was running on 8080 you could have used a url like `http://aem-publish.local:8080` to hit it.